# Inheritance confusion vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance

I searched over 20 articles and I am still slightly confused with inheritance. I have three classes as such:

```
Class A

    Private _Mode As String

    Public Function returnMode() As String
        Return _Mode
    End Function

Class B
    Inherits Class A

    Private _Mode As String = "modeb"

Class C
    Inherits Class A

    Private _Mode As String = "modec"
```

Now any time I create a B or C class, I would like the object to return the child class _Mode. I can make the New() function _Mode = "modeb" but I wanted to know a better way or more correct way.

How do I properly declare the variable _Mode?

Comment: `I may have found the correct answer` answer to what?  None of your posts ever actually ask a question.  It is never too late to read [Ask] or take the [Tour]

Comment: I want to call an instance of a class where the child class determines the values of a variable instead of the parent class. I want Class B to act like:

Private b As New B
b.returnMode()
- I want the last line to return modeb and not ""

^^^How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to make `_Mode` `Protected` instead of `Private` so you can set it from the subclasses, and set the value is the subclass constructors:

```
Class A

    Protected _Mode As String

    Public Function returnMode() As String
        Return _Mode
    End Function

Class B
    Inherits Class A

    Public Sub New()
        _Mode = "modeb"
    End Sub

Class C
    Inherits Class A

    Public Sub New()
        _Mode = "modec"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I meant and exactly how to do it. Thank you.